# Puppeteer throwing error during import : the "original" argument must be of type Function | Next Js

Tags: next.js, puppeteer, server-side-rendering, domparser

I am trying to use Puppeteer in my next js project for SSR. I need to parse the html string and modify it.

While trying to import puppeteer I am getting this error :

the "original" argument must be of type Function

Node version: 14

I have tried other parsing libraries like jsdom (which didn't work because of ShareArrayBuffer issue), looking for a solution with puppeteer.

```
Uncaught TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function
    at promisify (util.js?3022:614)
    at eval (index.js?6b55:11)
    at Object../node_modules/extract-zip/index.js (index.js?ts=1630396319822:1981)
    at Object.options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1630396319822:675)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1630396319822:37)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1630396319822:353)
    at eval (BrowserFetcher.js?aafb:48)
```